# How to use bcrypt to encrypt a date and decrypt it for comparison?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bcrypt

I am sending a token to user email like below and using bcrypt for this as an encrypt/decrypt mechanism.

```
  const token = await bcrypt.hash(joinDate, 10);
```

When the user clicks on the link in email, I get the above token back as that token is a part of
`/api/unsubscribe?userId="abcd"&token="token_that_was_generated_using_bcrypt_and_sent_to_user"`

```
const {userId, token} = req.query;
```

In the api, I am comparing joinDate obtained from database vs token sent by req.query but it never matches.

```
const joinDate = user.joinDate.toString();
const tokenValidated = await bcrypt.compare(joinDate, token)//this is always false although us generated from same joinDate field
```

Why is `tokenValidated` always false although it was generated using the same field joinDate?

Comment: Why bcrypt? Generate a (long enough) random number (or a GUID) and use that as token.

Comment: bcrypt is one way hash; using the word `decrypt` for bcrypt is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your use of bcrypt is not secure. Anyone can brute-force a few hundred or a few thousand dates and cause any user to become unsubscribed.

I assume your motivation is to avoid having to create a new table in your database and store a random token for every email you've sent out.

If so, the proper tool to use is HMAC.

Your URL should be of the form: `/api/unsubscribe?userId=abcd&mac=...`.

Come up with a secret key known only to your server. This secret key will be used to create and authenticate all unsubscribe requests. Only use this key for authenticating unsubscribe requests.

Perform HMAC-SHA512 on the user id, with the HMAC output truncated to 128 bits. Then base64-encode the 128 bits and set it as the `mac` parameter in the URL.

HMAC means to create a hash-based message authentication code, which will confirm to your server that it must have created and emailed out that 'mac'.

Now, your server can authenticate each response, because only someone with knowledge of the server's secret key can produce a valid unsubscribe link.

Comment: Thank you. My secret is `process.env.SESSION_SECRET`. Do I need to `npm install HMAC`? I would appreciate the syntax assuming my user ID is `userId`. I am assuming I need to do HMAC when generating the token(when sending email) and again when validating the unsubscribe request?

Comment: first of all attacker wouldn’t  know, that bcrypted hash is from joinDate; and it's impossible to leak; second point is that bcrypt is not brute-forcable

Comment: @Mhmdrz_A Kerckhoffs's principle states that systems should not rely on secrecy of the technique to be secure. Second, bcrypt is absolutely brute-forceable since there will only ever be a few thousand different dates that are possible.

Comment: @Mhmdrz_A That was my thought and joinDate also has timestamp so I did not think it would be insecure. I am willing to try this answer though as I am looking for a simple encrypt/validate.

Comment: Yes, HMAC will work like bcrypt, except that you use a secret in order to ensure that you are the only person that can create the output and verify the output. I don't have time right now to write all the code for you, but you should be able to find HMAC code examples on the web.

Comment: Also note that even if you are using a millisecond timestamp, it is possible your system may expose to the public the approximate date a user joined. It may appear in their public profile, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic of using bcrypt for hash and verifying on the other end  should work. The only possible thing that can prevent it from working is either:

1 - the joinDate here: `const token = await bcrypt.hash(joinDate, 10);`

is not `===`

to joinDate here:`const tokenValidated = await bcrypt.compare(joinDate, token)`

( maybe differes in `"`, `'` or different format orsomething )

2 - or the token is kinda different in `'` or `"` when passing through / read from queryparam; (e.g. you token is going `"'token_that_was_generated_using_bcrypt_and_sent_to_user'"` for comparison.)

Comment: What if the web site exposes the date the user joined the web site, as part of their public profile? What if someone posts a tweet saying they just signed up for this web site? This massively reduces the number of millisecond timestamps that need to be checked, allowing the Bcrypt token to be brute-forced. Bcrypt is the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: @AndrewParks yeah I got your point, and Kerckhoffs's principle you said was cool; but his technique should work though; even if is ultimately insecure. and I'm trying to see why it doesn't work, instead of offering a more secure solution

Comment: Fair enough, I agree you are more directly answering the actual question.

Comment: Will test it out. I am going to incorporate @AndrewParks comments and hash `joinDate`+`env.SECRET`. First need to figure out why the compare always fails. Thanks both